# How to output gunicorn log in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, gunicorn

I'm using Pycharm 2.7.1 and gunicorn. When I run gunicorn, I add a new Python Configuration. And I then add the command:

```
gunicorn_paster -c *.conf
```

If I want to view log, I will open the terminal and type the command:

```
tail -f /var/gunicorn/username/gunicorn-error.log
```

It is not convenient. I want to output the log in the pycharm console directly.
So, there is any suggestion for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is missing in PyCharm, vote for it:

- [PY-8859](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8859) Logs Tab in Run Configuration

Answer (score 1):

An easy way of showing gunicorns access log in the pycharm console it to use the `--access-logfile -` option. That will pipe the access log to stderr and thus the pycharm console window. Note the '-' at the end.